# Combining identical horizontal data points on a clustered bar graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

How would I go about clustering horizontal values that are the same. I.E. how would I go about making "Review" one cluster with two bars side-by-side? As can be seen in the provided screen shot, I've got the graph to show the statuses with the days they've been open, but it has them separated.

So far I've figured out that I need to set them up as series if I want them to show up as a cluster. The issue I'm running into now, is that I have several possible states for the change requests to be in, but they won't necessarily all have values at any one point. Do I have to have placeholder values for all of these, and if so how would that work with a dynamically populated data set from a sharepoint connection?

Looking at the third screen shot brings it closer to what I'm looking for. The source table will grow and shrink based on how long a change request is open and eventually completes. I need to account for this also. I want to have a graph like the one in my screenshot,  but instead of having two sections with "Review", I would have one section of "Review" but with two bars of different colors. If more requests are in the "Review" process, then more bars would appear.

[EDIT3] What I'm trying to do is making the ID the primary method of identification (possibly its own color?) then filtering it into bar sections based on it's status, and then show how many days this object has been active.

Clustered bar graph depicting change request statuses with days open:

> [image: Clustered bar graph depicting change request statuses with days open.]

Data used for the graph:

> [image: Data used for the graph.]

Example of where I want to go with this:

> [image: Example of where I want to go with this.]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. To get a more positive response to your question, you should add some details. A screenshot of the data would be helpful. You should also outline what you've already tried and your thoughts around why it might not be working.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you said. I've added a screenshot of the data that I'm using. I've made a little progress and I'm going to update the post with what I've found so far. I have no idea what I'm doing with graphs in excel, so what I've got so far in the screenshot is all I've got. Just the statuses lined up with the days. Just need identical statuses combined. I can't figure out why it's not combining, nor do I know how to get there. I've been working on this for a couple hour.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "combining"? Review should be 28 and Completed 19 (in your sample data)?

Comment: No, so I want there to be multiple sections. I'm about to update my original post with an example of how I want it to look.

Comment: So I guess more of what I'm trying to do is making the ID the primary method of identification (possibly its own color?) then filtering it into bar sections based on it's status, and then show how many days this object has been active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your data and use Insert>PivotChart.

Drag 'Location' and 'Created' into the 'Axis (Categories)' box, and drag the 'Days Open' into 'Values.

[image]

You can see that you have a bar for each created date within each location.

Alternatively, you can drag 'Created' into 'Legend (Series)' and get this:

[image]

All of the chart's properties can be configured using the Design tab on the ribbon while the chart is selected. So, I can remove the axis and the gridlines and add data labels. I can also right-click the chart and select 'Hide all field buttons on chart'. I can also add a title and end up with a much cleaner chart:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. A colleague was using pivot charts on another project a year ago and I completely forgot that's what they were using. Thank you so much for the guide on this, you're a lifesaver!